# Obtener los importes de cada mes en un año

Tags: mysql, sql

Dada una tabla de articulos en MySql, compueta por los campos:

- codart
- nomart
- desart
- precioart

Se desea obtener el importe total de las ventas de cada mes en un año dado.

Supongo que la idea es algo como esto pero la condicion no se como ponerla.

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure resumenMensual
(
    in anio year
)

BEGIN

    select sum(precioart)
    from articulos
    GROUP BY ...;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

tendrías que agrupar de manera adecuada en tu Consulta segun lo que necesites, asi que haras uso del **group by** ..
supongamos que tienes una tabla como esta:

```
Anio    Mes     Total
2018    Febrero     100
2018    Febrero     200
2018    Febrero     300
2018    Febrero     400
2018    Enero       1
2018    Enero       2
2018    Enero       3
2018    Enero       4
2018    Enero       5
```

Entonces para lo que requiera tu consulta seria asi:

```
SELECT Anio, Mes, SUM(Total) FROM miTabla GROUP BY Anio, Mes
```

Esta Consulta te retornara lo Siguiente:

```
Anio    Mes     Total
2018    Febrero 1000
2018    Enero   15
```

Si requieres un Año en especifico tendras que hacer uso de **WHERE** de la Siguiente manera: por ejemplo obtener solo el Año 2018 y el mes de Febrero:

```
SELECT Anio, Mes, SUM(Total) FROM miTabla WHERE Anio='2018'AND Mes='Febrero' GROUP BY Anio, Mes;
```

Esto te regresara solamente:

```
Anio    Mes     Total
2018    Febrero 1000
```

Comment: No se agrupa por la columna `Total`, solo seria `GROUP BY Anio, Mes`

Comment: Efectivamente.. tienes toda la razón olvide quitar el total, .. ya esta editado Recuerdos!!